# Testing SQLite code online

Tags: sqlite, ide

Is there any website which provides the service for testing SQLite code online?

For example, w3schools.com provides the service of working with SQL statements on their site.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Try [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5). It has several sql engines.

Comment: Almost a year later, but it may help others.

Comment: +1 Judging by the upvotes, it most certainly did.

Comment: Greate exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: https://kripken.github.io/sql.js/GUI/ - Demo with data.

Comment: SQLFiddle has been super slow lately, and today I haven't been able to execute any queries on a table with < 10 row.

Comment: http://sqliteonline.com/ might help.

Comment: Does anyone know, if I donate SQL FIddle, it would be work better?

Comment: @AndrewJens, thank you very match!

Comment: This helped me, thank you.